# jquery mobile and knockoutjs input type search binding issue

Tags: knockout.js

I am seeing a weird issue with knockoutjs and jquery mobile where if the input type is set to search, the binding fails, for the same code, if the input type is set to text, the binding succeeds. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
<form data-bind="jqmsubmit: search" >                   
  <input data-theme="b" name="search" id="search" type="search" data-bind="value: searchTerm"></input>
</form>
```

with the above code searchTerm is not updated when I type into the text box and press enter. If I change the input element to be type="text" searchTerm is updated as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input `type="search"` does not fire the `change` event but the `serach` event.

So you need to subscribe on the `search` event, you can do with using the `valueUpdate` setting of the `value` binding

```
<form data-bind="jqmsubmit: search" >                   
  <input data-theme="b" name="search" id="search" type="search" 
         data-bind="value: searchTerm, valueUpdate: ['search']">  
  </input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into this same issue. I think the problem has something to do with how jQuery Mobile replaces your **search** input elements with slightly different HTML than your **text** input elements. This workaround works for me:

```
<input type="search" 
       onkeyup="ko.contextFor(this).$data.searchTerm(this.value);"
       onchange="ko.contextFor(this).$data.searchTerm(this.value);"
       placeholder="Search" />
```